# Batch run for "git diff-tree"

Tags: git, git-diff-tree

I need to find the changes made by each commit.

So I used `git log` to find the list of all commits.

Then I use `git diff-tree current-commit previous-commit [some other options]` to find the changes.

The problem is the repo has more than 3000 commits, so doing 3000 `git diff-tree` is quite time-consuming ?

Is it possible to do a single `git diff-tree` (fed by the list of all commits) to get all the changes.

Comment: Just `git diff`?

Comment: @KamilCuk You mean a single `git diff` ? I did take a look at it already but failed to find the proper options/arguments

Comment: Why are you using git diff-tree in the first place? What's the goal? What does "find the changes" mean? Why wouldn't you just say `git log --patch` if you want to see all the changes between all successive commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log` can print the diff of each listed commit (the diff is hidden by default, turn it on with the `-p|--patch` option), and can take all the options accepted by `git diff` (`--name-only`, `--name-status`, options for merge commits, ...)

---

[@jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723269/86072) gives a set of options that basically outputs the same thing as `git diff-tree` for each commit.

You would have to describe in more details what information you are interested in if you want someone to provide you with a more suitable set of options.

Comment: Note that `git log -p` by default shows *nothing* for merge commits. Use `-m` to split merges, or since Git 2.31, one of the `--diff-merges` settings, to change this.

Comment: @torek I'll try -m and --diff-merges.

Answer (score 3):

```
git log  -m --raw --no-abbrev --oneline --all
```

or if you want to get cute see `git diff-tree`'s `--stdin` option.